# PHP 8.1 connecting to MS SQL 2008 R2

Tags: php, sql-server, wampserver, sqlsrv

I am working on a  small project where I should connect to ms sql 2008 r2 from the wamp server PHP 8.1

The client can not upgrade from the sql server 2008 r2 as their another software are confined with a particular system and can not udgrade.

I try to search the proper sqlsrv.dll driver for php 8.1 which support sql server 2008 R2. but unable to find it.

Can anyone pleae guide me how to connect the sql server 2008 R2 using php 8.1

Comment: use odbc https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php

Comment: I have installed the odbc driver 18 but unable to connect

Comment: then you need to do something, try to connect to it differently

Comment: Have you considered migrating your databases to a newer (supported) version of SQL Server? ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server doesn't support such an old version of SQL Server, you'll need to use ODBC Driver 17(.3) for SQL Server or earlier. Ref: [System requirements, installation, and driver files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files)

Comment: Try to downgrade your PHP version to PHP 7.3. More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver16).